# Passing arguments to python module

Tags: python

I want to pass arguments to the python module to help me decide whether or not to execute some part of the module initialisation code.

Suppose I have a python module named `my_module`

```
import sys

flag = sys.argv[1]

if (flag):
   # Do Some thing
else:
   # Do something else

def module_hello ():
    print "hello"
```

However, I don't want a user script to interfere with the arguments. It has to be purely based on parameters passed while spawning. In the environment where this will be used, I control the spawn of the script. But the script is provided by user of the module

Say a user writes script which imports this module

```
sys.argv[1] = "Change to something unpleasant"
import my_module
```

I don't want user to have control over sys.argv. The CLI arguments passed to the script should go to the module unharmed.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "python module"?

Comment: Python module is the same as library in other languages

Comment: Are you going to use module in python code or execute as script?

Comment: This module would be imported. There would be initialization code in the module which should be executed depending on the command line parameters.

Comment: You should probably include an example of what you tried in Python code and describe exactly what you want that it isn't doing - as it is currently written, it's unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: can't you do something like `python -m my_module script args`? That should load the module before the script.

Comment: If I understand OP correctly, in an ideal world he would like to control the access to the CLI arguments. There is currently no way to do this, that I am aware of. Either, stick to "access for all" to the CLI arguments, or implement another way of passing the arguments. One such approach could be a (temporary) file containing the arguments. The r/w rights to the file can be controlled.

Comment: @MA53QXR, That's exactly what I want. However, once my module is loaded with right arguments, I don't really care if anyone changes that.

Comment: @Heike: I can. If I do that, then I believe user won't even need to call import on my library. Right? In this case though, user's script would also become argument to the module. Will the user's script execute after module is loaded with ```python -m``` option?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to set some global values for a module, you should probably consider encapsulating it in a class, or setting them by calling an intialisation function, so you can pass the parameters like that.

`main.py`:

```
import my_module

my_module.init('some values')
```

`mymodule.py`:

```
VALUES = None


def init(values):
    global VALUES
    VALUES = values
```

But why not simply declare some variables in the module and just set the value when you load it?

`main.py`:

```
import my_module

my_module.values = 'some values'
```

`mymodule.py`:

```
values = None
```

Or if you just want to read the arguments, it's like any other script:
`main.py`:

```
import my_module
```

`mymodule.py`:

```
import sys

values = sys.argv[1]
```

Of course you can get as fancy as you like, read https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: This isn't what I am looking for. My requirement is that script importing the module should not interfere with those variables. The arguments should be passed as CLI arguments. I want to restrict the user of the module to modify the cli args

Comment: You want to pass parameters to the module as CLI arguments, but you also specified that you didn't want the module to interfere with the arguments? Which one is it? Do you or do you not want the module to read the arguments?

Comment: I want to pass parameters to the module as CLI arguments. AND the script which calls import on my module should not modify the arguments passed via CLI. In the module I want to get exactly what was passed via CLI. Script should not have any control on those arguments.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by having control over CLI arguments. Since only the script that imports the module *has* any CLI arguments, it will be able to access them - it doesn't have to, but it will be able to, before the module gets loaded.

Comment: In the environment where this will be used, I control the spawn of the script. User provides the script which I execute with command line parameters meant for my module. Since the arguments are meant for the module, if user modifies the argument, it will impact the workflow

Answer (score 0):

So, try to read arguments at your module.

*my-module.py*

```py
import sys

# Assign my module properties
is_debug = arg[1]
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the one who imports "my-module" can change arg[1]

Comment: Then passing arguments with CLI isn't right approach for you. You need something different.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you combine sys argv with os environ.

```
# my_module
import os
import sys

flag = sys.argv[1] or os.getenv('MY_FLAG')

if (flag):
   # Do Some thing
else:
   # Do something else

def module_hello ():
    print "hello"
```

Then user can write script like this:

```
# user script
import os
os.environ['MY_FLAG'] = 1
import my_module
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `sys.argv` for this when you `import` the module. I'm guessing you are looking for something like

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    do stuff with sys.argv
else:
    some other mechanism
```

As to what "some other mechanism" might mean, you have rejected the sane options that other answers have offered you, so I'm slightly at loss as to what would work for you. Perhaps reserve another variable which you have to set before you `import`? That's terribly ugly, but should do what you ask.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    flag = sys.argv[1]
else:
    flag = my_module_default_flag
```

You would then import it like this:

```
my_module_default_flag = "ugliness! ugliness!"
import my_module
```

Perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778466/ for an explanation of the `__name__` construct.

Actually, I lied before. There is nothing which technically prevents you from using `sys.argv` for this purpose; the value is not read-only or anything. But obviously, when you are doing an import from a different module, the sane expectation is that `sys.argv` should contain *its* command-line arguments. But you technically could do

```
sys.argv = [sys.argv[0], "ugliness! ugliness!"]
import my_module
```

I cannot recommend this, but if you are hellbent on plunging deeper into "doctor, it hurts when I do this" territory, this is one way to do that.